# Formula to make higher numbers harder to get in a random

Tags: java, random, formula

I'm looking for a formula or a method to allow getting higher numbers in a random harder to obtain. For instance if I was attempting to get a number out of 1000, getting 1000 would be much harder than getting a lower number such as 1 - 250.

Comment: can you tell us what have you tried?

Comment: How aggressive do you want to probability reduction to be? What shape do you want the reduction curve to have? Linear? Stepped? Convex? Concave?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use square roots, which make it easier to get higher numbers. We then subtract from 1,000 to make it easier to get lower numbers instead.

If the lowest value you want is zero:

```
1000 - (int) Math.sqrt(rand.nextInt(1001*1001))
```

If the lowest value you want is one:

```
1000 - (int) Math.sqrt(rand.nextInt(1000*1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, POisson distribution with `lambda` less than or equal to 1 would fit your requirements

```
public static int getPoisson(double lambda) {
  double L = Math.exp(-lambda);
  double p = 1.0;
  int k = 0;

  do {
    k++;
    p *= Math.random();
  } while (p > L);

  return k - 1;
}
```

call it with 1 and see if it is what you want

Answer (score -1):

Use a Rand for the high number, as in

```
highNum = Rand(1,4) *250;
randNum = Rand(1, highNum);
```

Using this formula, numbers between 1-250 have 8.3 times chance over numbers between 750-1000